# Sum of basis vectors of a vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\{a_{1},\cdot\cdot\cdot a_{n}\}$ and $\{b_{1},\cdot\cdot\cdot b_{n}\}$ be two basis of $\mathbb{R}^{n}.$ Let $P$ be a square  matrix of order $n$ with real entries such that $P(a_{i})=b_{i},i=1,2,\cdot\cdot\cdot n$. Suppose that every eigenvalue of $P$ is either $-1$or$1.$ My question is that whether the set $\{a_{i}+2b_{i}|i=1,2,\cdot\cdot\cdot n\}$  is also a basis or not? I tried with example  its always found to be a basis. Please suggest me right concept. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $P(a_i)=b_i,\forall i,$ we know that $(I+2P)(a_i)=a_i+2b_i.$
Now if $\det(I+2P)=0,$ then the characteristic polynomial of $P$ has a root $=-1/2.$ But this contradicts that every eigenvalue of $P$ is either $1$ or $-1.$ So $I+2P$ is an invertible matrix, thus $\{a_i+2b_i\}$ also forms a basis.

Hope this helps.

Comment: very nice answer....thanks a lot....

Comment: It is my pleasure to help. :D